# SQL Inner Join using Distinct and Order by Desc

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

table a. [image: Table a]
Table b . [image]I have two tables. Table A has over 8000+ records and continues to grow with time. 
Table B has only 5 or so records and grows rarely but does grow sometimes.

I want to query Table A's last records where the Id for Table A matches for Table B. The problem is; I am getting all the rows from Table A. I just need the ones where Table A and B match once. These are unique Id's when a new row is inserted into table B and never get repeated.

Any help is most appreciated.

```
SELECT a.nshift, 
       a.loeeworkcellid, 
       b.loeeconfigworkcellid, 
       b.loeescheduleid, 
       b.sdescription, 
       b.sshortname 
FROM   oeeworkcell a 
       INNER JOIN dbo.oeeconfigworkcell b 
               ON a.loeeconfigworkcellid = b.loeeconfigworkcellid 
ORDER  BY a.loeeworkcellid DESC
```

Comment: i think what you're looking for is `GROUP BY`, but I don't understand your question well enough to give much more info.

Comment: You are using an `INNER JOIN`, you **should be** getting only rows that match on both tables

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, could you add a small sample of data from both tables and desired output?

Comment: Ok, you updated your question to show everything but the result that you want

Comment: Thats where I am having trouble with... the result.... I just need the same amount of rows as in Table B, but bringing in Table A's shift number associated with lOeeConfigWorkCellId

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you want to get the only the `lastest` (as you said) row from the `TableA` but `JOIN` giving you all the rows.You can use the [Row_Number()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186734.aspx) to get the rownumber and then apply the join and filter it with the `Where` clause to select only the first row from the `JOIN`. So what you can try as below,

```
;WITH CTE 
AS
(
   SELECT * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY loeeconfigworkcellid  ORDER BY loeeworkcellid desc) AS Rn
   FROM oeeworkcell 
)


SELECT a.nshift, 
       a.loeeworkcellid, 
       b.loeecoonfigworkcellid, 
       b.loeescheduleid, 
       b.sdescription, 
       b.sshortname 
FROM   CTE a 
       INNER JOIN dbo.oeeconfigworkcell b 
               ON a.loeeconfigworkcellid = b.loeeconfigworkcellid 
WHERE
    a.Rn = 1
```

Comment: I tried this. It gives me only one record. I need to have the same amount of rows as in Table B, but associating the nShift from Table A where the Id's match

Comment: Thank you. It worked nicely. Ill try to be more clear in my questions next time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to group by your data and select only the data having the condition with min id.

```
SELECT a.nshift, 
       a.loeeworkcellid, 
       b.loeecoonfigworkcellid, 
       b.loeescheduleid, 
       b.sdescription, 
       b.sshortname 
FROM   oeeworkcell a 
INNER JOIN dbo.oeeconfigworkcell b 
ON a.loeeconfigworkcellid = b.loeeconfigworkcellid 
group by 
a.nshift, 
       a.loeeworkcellid, 
       b.loeecoonfigworkcellid, 
       b.loeescheduleid, 
       b.sdescription, 
       b.sshortname 
having a.loeeworkcellid = min(a.loeeworkcellid)
```

Comment: This gives me all 8000 rows